# Data extraction from HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to pull data from html text.

I am having an issue with the extraction code.

Normally I deal with `div` or `Li`, this html seems to be a bit more complicated.
It is using **Div id**, **ul Class** and **Span Class**.

What do I put in for `Class` or `Li` extraction?

[image: HTML Image]

```
For Each li In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("li")
    If li.getAttribute("class") = "a-link-normal" Then 
        Set link = li.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
        .Cells(i, 1).Value = link.getAttribute("href")
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next li
```

I have also posted this [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/data-extraction-from-html.1147850/).

The new code from PEH seems to work.

[image: URL IMAGE]

However I am getting an error message.

[image: Error Message 1]

**Error Line In Code**

[image: Error in code]

Comment: You forgot to tell what is wrong with your code. Which errors do you get, where did you get stuck? We need some description of what went wrong, *"not working"* is not a useful error description.

Comment: Sorry my fault, the code is not pulling off anything, Im not sure if i am putting in the right class, li, and so on. normally the website HTML is straight forward and i only need to change the class or change the div to a li. However with this html I am not as sure

Comment: Did you go through your code step by step using F8? This way you can investigate what is going on and check your variable values.

Comment: Yes, the code does NOT show any errors, from start to finish it completes fine and the message box pops up at the end to say ALL done. I know the code works for a more simpler HTML code, where by the CLASS or Li name needs to be changed. Here I am not sure if I am placing the right one to pull off the data. I just need a bit of guidance on which tag to place in the code to pull off the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code `If li.getAttribute("class") = "a-link-normal" Then` you check if the current `li` has a class attribute `a-link-normal` like `<li class="a-link-normal">` but is is actually a link element with the class `a-link-normal` and not a list element. So I think it should be somehow like this:

```
For Each li In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("li")        
    Set link = li.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    If link.getAttribute("class") = "a-link-normal" Then 
        .Cells(i, 1).Value = link.getAttribute("href")
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next li
```

You might come accross `<li>` elements that have no links `<a>` inside.

```
For Each li In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("li")
    Set link = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next        
    Set link = li.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    On Error Goto 0

    If Not link Is Nothing Then 
        If link.getAttribute("class") = "a-link-normal" Then 
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = link.getAttribute("href")
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End if
Next li
```

Comment: super, this is a lot better, however I am getting an error message. I will update my original question with an update

Comment: the error probably means that you came accross a `<li>` element that has no `<a>` link element. Check `If Not link Is Nothing Then` see updated answer.

Comment: Super, that done the trick. Big Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler and faster to just use the class direct. The css class selector "." shown below is combined with href attribute selector [href] so you only retrieve elements that match that class and have an href attribute

```
Dim items As Object

Set items = HTMLdoc.querySelectorAll(".a-link-normal[href]")

For i = 0 To items.Length - 1
   
    .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = items.item(i).href

End If
```

Comment: Would probably work too, but doesn't force the link items to be in `li` elements if there are some outside `li` this will catch them too I think. But definitely nicer solution.